# Is it possible to to auto detect otp number in android webview?

Tags: android, webview, one-time-password

I am developing webview app. I want to auto detect otp number received in mobile to input field. Is it possible in android webview?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try defining a JS function inside like :

```
document.getElementsByTagName(\"input\")
```